# How to convert a string into object

Tags: python, string, object

How i call an object from a string.

This is my code:

```
 Class main:

 a=(input("file name"))
 b=(input("insert a word"))
 archive.relacao(b,a)

 Class archive:
  def relacao(self,word,document):
    t=doc.contsimple()[word]
```

The method contsimple is in the class Document

the error is:
NameError: global name 'doc' is not defined

Comment: Could you explain more on what you want yo do?

Comment: The input is recieved has str wich is the document name, and i want to convert into an object from the type Document to call the method contsimple

Comment: Ok, could you post the class `Document`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work if you do this?

```
Class main:

    a=(input("file name"))
    b=(input("insert a word"))
    archive.relacao(b,a)

Class archive:
    def relacao(self,word,document):
    t=document.contsimple()[word]
```

Because that immediately stands out to me - archive.relacao is passed the file name, which is takes as `document`. But `document` is not used - `doc` is used. `doc` is not defined, hence the name error.

Comment: ok, now it gives me another error: t=Document.contagemsimple()[word] TypeError: contagemsimple() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Answer (score 0):

Well there a couple of things that can cause that error:

**Be sure you define `doc` before use it.**

Python is an interpreted language, so if the

```
t=doc.contsimple()[word]
```

statement is before you define some `doc` object Python will complain about that.

**You meant `document` instead doc**

The function `relacao` is receiving a `document` argument, so maybe you mistype the `doc` var.
change:

```
t=doc.contsimple()[word]
```

to:

```
t=document.contsimple()[word]
```

Comment: ok,
now it gives me another error:
 t=Document.contagemsimple()[word]
TypeError: contagemsimple() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: you write `Document` with a 'D' you have to write `document` with a 'd'. `t=document.contagemsimple()[word]`

Comment: it has to be Document because that is the class name.
if i write document it says that not defined